# Find the area of the parallelogram determined by vectors $\vec m$ and $\vec n$

Tags: geometry, vectors, area, absolute-value, cross-product

> Given vectors:
>   $$|\vec a|=2\\|\vec b|=4\\\angle(\vec a,\vec b)=\frac{2\pi}{3}\\\vec m=2\vec a+5\vec b\\\vec n=3\vec a-\vec b$$
>   Find the area of the parallelogram determined by vectors $\vec m$ and $\vec n$.

This is my solution:
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}A&=|(2\vec a+5\vec b)\times(3\vec a-\vec b)|\\&=|\cancel{2\vec a\times3\vec a}-2\vec a\times\vec b+15\vec b\times\vec a-\cancel{5\vec b\times\vec b}|\\&=|-16\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}-120\cdot\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}|\\&=68\sqrt 3\end{align}$$
But, in my book the solution is $34\sqrt 3$. Where did I make a mistake? I noticed that my solution is twice of the actual result, so maybe I made some stupid mistake in my calculations, but I cannot figure out where.

Comment: I think your book is wrong! Your solution is true.

Comment: May be the question is about the triangle not about the parallelogram.

Comment: @Ahmed. It says "parallelogram".

Comment: @s28t344hgug9jyn2y934tr In your proof must be $2\vec{a}\times3\vec{a}=\vec{0}$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. Thank you. I just corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is true. There is a little mistake:

In your proof must be $2\vec{a}\times3\vec{a}=\vec{0}$, but the answer is right.

Your book does not know, how to calculate the area of parallelogram.

I think your book calculated an area of the triangle.